# Display API call data to new View

Tags: swift, api, swiftui

Attempting to display text to a view once my API call is complete. When a user submits there textfield, in `onSubmit`, I save the variable to my Binding foodName, which then gets passed to the new View (searchResultsView) If I display the data as Text, it works, but once I attempt to pass the data and display it in a separate view it does not.

My guess is I'm loading the view before the api call (or I could be completely off with my guess which I probably am). Any feedback would be helpful. Thank you.

**API CALL**

```
class FoodApiSearch: ObservableObject{
    @Published var foodDescription = ""
    //will search for user Input
    func searchFood(userItem: String){
       //calls api search
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?query=\(userItem)&dataType=&pageSize=1&pageNumber=1&api_key=***tDvDZVOy8cqG") else {return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _,_) in
            let searchResults = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APISearchResults.self, from: data!)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for item in searchResults.foods{
                        self.foodDescription = item.foodDescription ?? "food not valid"
                        print(self.foodDescription)
                    }
               
                }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

**Struct that calls SearchResultsView**

```
struct testA: View {
    //Textfield
    @State var userFoodInput = ""
    @State private var didUserSearch = false
    //will store api var of foodName
    @StateObject private var foodApi = FoodApiSearch()
    //send to food results view
    @State private var  foodName = ""
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                TextField("enter first name", text: $userFoodInput)
                    .onSubmit {
                        didUserSearch = true
                        foodApi.searchFood(userItem: userFoodInput)
                        foodName = foodApi.foodDescription
                    }
                
                FoodSearchResultsView(foodName: $foodName, userSearch: $didUserSearch)
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchResultsView (view being called)**

```
struct FoodSearchResultsView: View {
    //calls API
    @StateObject private var foodApi = FoodApiSearch()
    @State private var searchResultsItem = ""
    @Binding var foodName: String
    //if toggled, will display, binded to search bar
    @Binding var userSearch: Bool
  
    var body: some View {
        if userSearch{
            VStack{
                Text("Best Match")
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(foodName)
                        Text("1 Cup")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .offset(y:8)
                        }
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("72 Cals")
                }
                
                .frame(width:225, height:50)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 45)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(
                    cornerRadius:20).fill(Color("LightWhite")))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                Button("Add Food"){
                   userSearch = false
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: 700)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you set didSearch at the end of onSubmit ?

Comment: You don’t need to have FoodApiSearch as `StateObject` again in `FoodSearchResultsView` , make it an `@ObservedObject  var foodApi:FoodApiSearch` instead and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion was about right:

when you do:

```
foodName = foodApi.foodDescription
```

the network call did not finish yet.

Restructure your code. there is no need for the `foodName` variable as you have allready one in your `FoodApiSearch`. Pass that on to your subview and access it there. As soon as the network call completes it should update your view and show the result.

```
struct testA: View {
    //Textfield
    @State var userFoodInput = ""
    @State private var didUserSearch = false
    //will store api var of foodName
    @StateObject private var foodApi = FoodApiSearch()
    //send to food results view
    //@State private var  foodName = ""
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                TextField("enter first name", text: $userFoodInput)
                    .onSubmit {
                        didUserSearch = true
                        foodApi.searchFood(userItem: userFoodInput)
//                        foodName = foodApi.foodDescription
                    }
                
                FoodSearchResultsView(userSearch: $didUserSearch)
                    .environmentObject(foodApi)
        }
    }
}

struct FoodSearchResultsView: View {
    //calls API
    @EnvironmentObject private var foodApi: FoodApiSearch
    @State private var searchResultsItem = ""
//    @Binding var foodName: String
    //if toggled, will display, binded to search bar
    @Binding var userSearch: Bool
  
    var body: some View {
        if userSearch{
            VStack{
                Text("Best Match")
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(foodApi.foodDescription)
                        Text("1 Cup")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .offset(y:8)
                        }
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("72 Cals")
                }
                
                .frame(width:225, height:50)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 45)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(
                    cornerRadius:20).fill(Color("LightWhite")))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                Button("Add Food"){
                   userSearch = false
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: 700)
        }
    }
}
```